# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient - Custom HTTP Headers not sent

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to send custom HTTP Headers with a JsonServiceClient but headers are never sent in the query.

I'm using:

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient (baseUri);
client.Headers.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", "XXXXXX");
client.Headers.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "XXXXXX");
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't made a request yet. The [Headers get added here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c3f8107fcc047a1ff74f375e53d84294335a6f35/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceClientBase.cs#L835) when you make a request.

An alternative way to add headers is to use the Request filters, e.g:

```
client.RequestFilter = httpReq => {
    httpReq.Headers.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", "XXXXXX");
    httpReq.Headers.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "XXXXXX");
};
```

Which effectively does the same thing.

Comment: I found this as a workaround and tried it. The following get through:


 - Content-Type
 - session-id


This one does not:


`client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter = x => { x.Headers.Add("Authorization-KAPI", AuthorizationKAPI); };`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.

```
_client.RequestFilter = httpReq => httpReq.Headers.Add("X-CUSTOM", "hello");
```