# ServiceStack intercept requests before they are sent client side

Tags: servicestack

I have implemented a custom HMAC authentication for servicestack (example shown [here](http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/authenticating-servicestack-rest-api-using-hmac/)). As suggested at the bottom of the link, I wanted to do something like this client side:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient();

client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter +=
    delegate(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            // ContentType still null at this point so we must hard code it
            // Set these fields before trying to create the token!
            request.ContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json;
            request.Date = DateTime.Now;

            var secret = "5771CC06-B86D-41A6-AB39-9CA2BA338E27";
            var token = ApiSignature.CreateToken(request, secret);
            request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.UserId, "1");
            request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.Signature, token);
        };
```

which appends the authentication headers for every request sent to the API from this client. However `LocalHttpWebRequestFilter` doesn't seem to be a property of `JsonServiceClient` anymore. Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Instead of using `LocalHttpWebRequestFilter`, need to just use `RequestFilter`. The final solution looks like this:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient();

client.RequestFilter +=
  delegate(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        // ContentType still null at this point so we must hard code it
        // Set these fields before trying to create the token!
        request.ContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json;
        request.Date = DateTime.Now;

        var secret = "5771CC06-B86D-41A6-AB39-9CA2BA338E27";
        var token = ApiSignature.CreateToken(request, secret);
        request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.UserId, "1");
        request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.Signature, token);
    };
```

Credit for the solution here: [ServiceStack JsonServiceClient - Custom HTTP Headers not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613773/servicestack-jsonserviceclient-custom-http-headers-not-sent)

Comment: Yep v3's `LocalHttpWebRequestFilter` was renamed to `RequestFilter` in v4. The [bottom of v4's release notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2014/release-notes.md#the-big-refactor-of-v4) lists other changes that were refactored in v4.