# Building out first client using ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying out ServiceStack for connecting to an OAuth2 / JSON service. (C#)

First I'm struggling to find a good example of this out there as it appears most examples are using v3 of ServiceStack.  So if you're aware of a good example to work off of that would be great.

I'm working with the example code on SO question: [ServiceStack intercept requests before they are sent client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347698/servicestack-intercept-requests-before-they-are-sent-client-side)

But I'm having a hard time finding the correct NUGET packages to install.

I've got NUGET packages ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Client, ServiceStack.Common and ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2, ServiceStack.HttpClient.

I'm still not able to resolve:

```
request.ContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json;
```

Namespace name "web" does not exist in the namespace ServiceStack.Common

and

```
request.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.UserId, "1");
```

ApiCustomHttpHeaders does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the linked answer indicates you need to use `RequestFilter` in ServiceStack v4+. The MimeTypes are available in `MimeTypes` static class, otherwise you can use the JSON Content-Type `application/json`, e.g:

```
client.RequestFilter = req =>
{
    // ContentType still null at this point so we must hard code it
    // Set these fields before trying to create the token!
    request.ContentType = MimeTypes.Json;
    request.Date = DateTime.Now;

    var secret = "5771CC06-B86D-41A6-AB39-9CA2BA338E27";
    var token = ApiSignature.CreateToken(request, secret);
    req.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.UserId, "1");
    req.Headers.Add(ApiCustomHttpHeaders.Signature, token);
};
```

Comment: What is the variable request in the above example?  Also, I still cannot resolve ApiCustomHttpHeaders.  What namespace does that exist in?

Comment: @DaBlue that's from the answer you linked to, the [ApiCustomHttpHeaders comes from the linked example](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/authenticating-servicestack-rest-api-using-hmac/).